# My question is about transferring saplings from water soil in pots

Tags: propagation

Saplings have shoots after 2-3 weeks & very small roots seen in some cuttings. Can I use a rooting hormone on their roots & transfer into soil now?

Comment: Saplings of what plant?

Comment: Please send pictures and as much information as you are able.  Water roots are different than soil roots.  But this may be possible depending on a number of factors, first is what plant?  Pictures, please.